# How to append and update cookie in C#?

Tags: c#

I am storing some information in cookies key name is like this:

`[Id, Count, Name]`

It's storing like this, separated by pipe symbol there are 3 products into cookie.

You can see first and second product are the same.

- It should not repeat.
- Its count should be *increased* by one.

My output is as below:

```
Id=1&Count=1&Name=ABC | Id=1&Count=1&Name=ABC | Id=2&Count=1&Name=XYZ
```

Desired output [here count = 2 in first product]

```
Id=1&Count=2&Name=ABC | Id=2&Count=1&Name=XYZ
```

Comment: Show us your code and outline the parts you're having difficulties with.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how many products do you have.

But if you want to store some products in cookies like this, you can `Serialize` your product objects. And then if your cookie with `productId` does not exist, you can create it.

```
var cookie=Request.Cookies["ProductId"];
if(cookie==null)
{
   //Create your cookie
}
else
{
    //Modify cookie
    Request.Cookies["ProductId"].Value=SerializedObject
}
```

Comment: I think you need to copy your cookie over to the Response for it to be sent to the browser